# Firebase Fanout Structure List Query

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

For the Firebase fanout data structure [example](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/structure-data#fanout) of users and groups, what would be the most efficient way to retrieve user/member ("users") detail data for a given group from the "groups" list? Let's say the goal was to display the `"name"` property for **each** member of group `"techpioneers"`?

```
{
  "users": {
    "alovelace": {
      "name": "Ada Lovelace",
      "groups": {
         "techpioneers": true,
         "womentechmakers": true
      }
    },
  },
  "groups": {
    "techpioneers": {
      "name": "Historical Tech Pioneers",
      "members": {
        "alovelace": true,
        "ghopper": true
      }
    },
    ...
  }
}
```

Would using a combination of [orderByChild()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Query#orderByChild) and [equalTo()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Query#equalTo) be the best approach to find users who have `"techpioneers"` key and get at each of their data such as the `"name"` property? How would you access a property such as "name" once you've determined which users are part of the target group?

```
let usersRef = firebase.database().ref('users')
usersRef.orderByChild("groups").equalTo('techpioneers').on('child_added', (snapshot) => {
   // how would you access user "alovelace" name property?
   console.log(snapshot.val().name);
});
```

Thank you for any help you can provide.